# why selector in replicaSet Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bd6P3.jpg)I don't' see why adding selector when we are creating **replicaSet** I thought maybe we can select different pod but we can't so I don't see what is used for

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: ReplicaSet
metadata:
    name: rs-name
spec:
    replicas: 2
    selector: // here the selector
        matchLabels:
            podptr: my-pod-l
    template:
        metadata:
            name: pods-name
            labels:
                podptr: my-pod-l // here it's lable
        spec:
            containers:
                - name: cons-name
                  image: nginx
                  ports:
                      - containerPort: 50
```

Comment: The `template:` can be changed, but the `selector:` can't.  Without the `selector:`, if you changed the `labels:` in the pod spec, the replica set could forget about the pods it was previously managing.  (Also note it's rare to directly create a ReplicaSet; it's usually managed via a Deployment controller.)

Comment: thank you sir but why would i ever change the labels of pod after i create them and i think for this problem replicaSet would give it like random number to track it and 
 and even some how needed other label to use in other place like (service) i can just add label thanks sir

Answer (score 1):

Because you can have more than one label on the resulting pods and it doesn't know which of them to use for tracking. The selector labels are read-only once initialized, but other labels you can add and remove as needed for other purposes.

Comment: thank you  but i do not see where i will need to change my labels for other uses and because in deployment or replicaSet yaml file we can only make one pod i guess kubernetes would make automatic by giving that pod in that file some number to track it with and i make 2 replicaSet that uses the same labels in pods each file has 1 replica and pods have the same label and none of them got deleted even with replica 1 so if replicaSet uses labels it should remove one pod but this is not the case so please if you know the answer replay thanks